# replica Set mongo docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to configure a mongodb replicaSet using docker-compose, but when I stop the master container it seems that it doesn't pass to the secondary.

```
redis:
 image: redis
 ports:
  - "6379:6379"

mongo3:
 hostname: mongo3
 image: mongo
 entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs", "--journal","--dbpath","/data/db","--smallfiles", "--rest" ]
 volumes:
  - ./data/mongo3:/data/db
 ports:
  - "27018:27017"
  - "28018:28017"
 restart: always

mongo2:
 hostname: mongo2
 image: mongo
 entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs", "--journal","--dbpath","/data/db","--smallfiles", "--rest" ]
 volumes:
  - ./data/mongo2:/data/db
 ports:
  - "27019:27017"
  - "28019:28017"
 restart: always

mongo1:
 hostname: mongo1
 image: mongo
 entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet", "rs", "--journal","--dbpath","/data/db","--smallfiles", "--rest" ]
 volumes:
  - ./data/mongo1:/data/db
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
  - "28017:28017"
links:
 - mongo2:mongo2
 - mongo3:mongo3
restart: always

web:
 build: .
 ports:
  - "2000:2000"
 volumes:
  - .:/vip
 links:
  - redis
  - mongo1
  - mongo2
  - mongo3

nginx:
 restart: always
 build: ./nginx/
 ports:
  - "80:80"
 links:
  - web:web

mongosetup:
 image: mongo
 links:
  - mongo1:mongo1
  - mongo2:mongo2
  - mongo3:mongo3
 volumes:
  - ./scripts:/scripts
 entrypoint: [ "/scripts/setup.sh" ]
```

setup.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGODB1=`ping -c 1 mongo1 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`
MONGODB2=`ping -c 1 mongo2 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`
MONGODB3=`ping -c 1 mongo3 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`

echo "**********************************************" ${MONGODB1}
echo "Waiting for startup.."
until curl http://${MONGODB1}:28017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

echo curl http://${MONGODB1}:28017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1
echo "Started.."


echo SETUP.sh time now: `date +"%T" `
mongo --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 <<EOF
var cfg = {
    "_id": "rs",
    "version": 1,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "host": "${MONGODB1}:27017",
            "priority": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "host": "${MONGODB2}:27017",
            "priority": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "host": "${MONGODB3}:27017",
            "priority": 0
        }
    ],settings: {chainingAllowed: true}
};
rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
rs.slaveOk();
db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
db.getMongo().setSlaveOk(); 
EOF
```

Comment: check this https://smaillns.medium.com/set-up-a-mongodb-replicaset-using-docker-799029493edf

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar issue and resolved it with the following compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:4.2
    container_name: mongo1
    command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30001"]
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo-1:/data/db
    ports:
      - 30001:30001
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate({_id:'my-replica-set',members:[{_id:0,host:\"mongo1:30001\"},{_id:1,host:\"mongo2:30002\"},{_id:2,host:\"mongo3:30003\"}]}).ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo --port 30001 --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s

  mongo2:
    image: mongo:4.2
    container_name: mongo2
    command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30002"]
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo-2:/data/db
    ports:
      - 30002:30002

  mongo3:
    image: mongo:4.2
    container_name: mongo3
    command: ["--replSet", "my-replica-set", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "30003"]
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo-3:/data/db
    ports:
      - 30003:30003
```

with the following in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       mongo1
127.0.0.1       mongo2
127.0.0.1       mongo3
```

I documented it in a GitHub repo and with a little blog post here:

https://github.com/UpSync-Dev/docker-compose-mongo-replica-set

https://www.upsync.dev/2021/02/02/run-mongo-replica-set.html

Comment: I tried this out and it worked really well! I hope this will be the accepted answer

Comment: Looks like this runs rs.initiate() every 10 seconds? Why would you do that?

Answer (score 15):

Update: This does not work! You do need to run `rs.initiate()`

With MongoDB 4.0, you don't need a 4th container to run a setup script. It is really simple to bring up a replicaSet of 3 containers:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: localmongo1
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    expose:
      - 27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo2:
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: localmongo2
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    expose:
      - 27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo3:
    hostname: mongo3
    container_name: localmongo3
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    expose:
      - 27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
```

More info here: https://github.com/msound/localmongo/tree/4.0

Comment: don't you sill need to run rs.initiate(...) and possibly rs.add(...) on one of the nodes manually? if not, what part of the docker-compose yaml you posted takes care of that?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/ says you do.

Comment: also, don't forget: rs.slaveOk()

Comment: mongodb2     | 2019-06-28T02:04:15.218+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to lock the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Unknown error). Another mongod instance is already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
mongodb2

Comment: For those looking to include `rs.initiate()` call into your docker compose, you will need to use a `healthcheck` property to do that. See this answer on related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755872/3493695

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for how to start MongoDB Replica Set with one DB instance for local development and ended up here. I found the answers here too complicated, so I came up with the following solution:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services: 
  mongo:
    hostname: mongodb
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]
```

And there is a folder called 'scripts' in the current directory with a single file in it called 'init.js' (the name is not important). This folder mounted as a volume to the '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/', which is a special folder. When MongoDB is started, all the files in this directory will be executed. The content of file is:

**init.js**

```
rs.initiate();
```

Comment: with this way i do not have access to the data inside my collections. I get the following error: ```Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "node is not in primary or recovering state",
 "code" : 13436,
 "codeName" : "NotMasterOrSecondary"
}
```

Comment: @gustavz make sure you have correctly structured your files. Otherwise, run 'rs.initiate()' from mongo CLI client.

Comment: In mongodb 5.0, is work, and the volumes is require. In mongodb 4.x volumes do not need.

Comment: Is this then only using one container, yet representing a replica set to the client? Will code needing a replica set (like transactions) still work?

Comment: The addition of the "hostname" parameter solved my issue which is documented in the topic below. Essentially the container id was being used as the hostname. When the container was replaced, the shards could no longer connect to the config server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747148/upgrading-a-sharded-mongodb-cluster-in-docker-container-id-being-used-to-connec

Answer (score 4):

I would adivse you to have a look at [khezen/mongo](https://github.com/Khezen/docker-mongo).

You can deploy a mongo replica set across a 3 nodes docker swarm with the following:

```
version: '3'

services:

  replica1:
    image: khezen/mongo:slim
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      palcement:
        node.hostname: node-1
    environment:
      RS_NAME: shard1
      SHARD_SVR: 'y'
      AUTH: 'y'
    volumes:
      - /data/mongo/replica1:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo_cluster

  replica2:
    image: khezen/mongo:slim
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      palcement:
        node.hostname: node-2
    environment:
      RS_NAME: shard1
      SHARD_SVR: 'y'
      AUTH: 'y'
    volumes:
      - /data/mongo/replica2:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo_cluster

  replica3:
    image: khezen/mongo:slim
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      palcement:
        node.hostname: node-3
    environment:
      RS_NAME: shard1
      SHARD_SVR: 'y'
      MASTER: replica3
      SLAVES: replica1 replica2
      AUTH: 'y'
    volumes:
      - /data/mongo/replica3:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo_cluster

networks:
  mongo_cluster:
    driver: overlay
```

*disclaimer: I am the maintainer of this image.*

Comment: Hey how would you go about connecting to these? I'm currently trying to automate my entire deployment via my docker-compose but here I see you're not exposing any of the ports to the rest of the world?

Comment: @EvanBurbidge You'd need to target of the replicaset by some service and target the appropriate pod/container - just opening the ports or going through a L4 Load Balancer won't do b/c you aren't guaranteed to be connecting to the RS Leader.

Answer (score 1):

I set up a gist with a guide on how to set it up using a docker-compose file and mongoose. https://gist.github.com/harveyconnor/518e088bad23a273cae6ba7fc4643549

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem in setting `replica set` up in a standalone `mongodb` service with authentication and here are what I ended up with.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  
  ...

  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME: ${MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME}
    command: ["--replSet", "${MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME}", "--bind_ip_all"]
    healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.status().ok" | mongo -u $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME} -p $${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD} --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
      start_period: 30s
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
      - ./scripts/set-credentials.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/set-credentials.sh

  replica-setup:
    image: mongo
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      default:
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/setup-replica.sh:/scripts/setup-replica.sh
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "/scripts/setup-replica.sh" ]
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

./scripts/setup-replica.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGODB1=db

echo "Waiting for MongoDB startup..."
until curl http://${MONGODB1}:27017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

# check if replica set is already initiated
RS_STATUS=$( mongo --quiet --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval "rs.status().ok" )
if [[ $RS_STATUS != 1 ]]
then
  echo "[INFO] Replication set config invalid. Reconfiguring now."
  RS_CONFIG_STATUS=$( mongo --quiet --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval "rs.status().codeName" )
  if [[ $RS_CONFIG_STATUS == 'InvalidReplicaSetConfig' ]]
  then
    mongo --quiet --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD <<EOF
config = rs.config()
config.members[0].host = db # Here is important to set the host name of the db instance
rs.reconfig(config, {force: true})
EOF
  else
    echo "[INFO] MongoDB setup finished. Initiating replicata set."
    mongo --quiet --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval "rs.initiate()" > /dev/null
  fi
else
  echo "[INFO] Replication set already initiated."
fi
```

./scripts/set-credentials.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mongo -- "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" <<EOF
    var rootUser = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME';
    var rootPassword = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD';
    var admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
    admin.auth(rootUser, rootPassword);

    var user = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME';
    var password = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD';
    db.createUser({user: user, pwd: password, roles: ["readWrite"]});
EOF
```

What I achieved through is:

- Setup a `mongodb` service with username/password authentication for a default collection
- Initialize `replica set` when it's first time running services
- Reconfigure `replica set` member when there's a previous db data
- Health check the `mongodb` service by checking `replica set` status

Comment: don't you have to pass in the --auth flag when starting mongod?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need single node replica set of MongoDB via docker-compose.yml you can simply use this:

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo:5
  restart: always
  command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]
  ports:
    - 27018:27017
  healthcheck:
    test: mongo --eval "rs.initiate()"
    start_period: 5s
```

Answer (score 0):

This setup works for me. I have also setup everything in https://github.com/nguyenduyhust/docker-mongodb-replica-set.

Great if that's what you're looking for.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mongo
RUN mkdir /config
WORKDIR /config
COPY wait-for-it.sh .
COPY mongo-setup.js .
COPY mongo-setup.sh .
RUN chmod +x /config/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x /config/mongo-setup.sh
CMD [ "bash", "-c", "/config/wait-for-it.sh mongodb1:27011 -- /config/mongo-setup.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  mongodb1:
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mongodb1:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27011:27011"
    expose:
      - "27011"
    entrypoint:
      [
        "/usr/bin/mongod",
        "--port", "27011",
        "--replSet", "rs0",
        "--bind_ip_all",
      ]

  mongodb2:
    container_name: mongo2
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mongodb2:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27012:27012"
    expose:
      - "27012"
    entrypoint:
      [
        "/usr/bin/mongod",
        "--port", "27012",
        "--replSet", "rs0",
        "--bind_ip_all",
      ]

  mongodb3:
    container_name: mongo3
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/mongodb3:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27013:27013"
    expose:
      - "27013"
    entrypoint:
      [
        "/usr/bin/mongod",
        "--port", "27013",
        "--replSet", "rs0",
        "--bind_ip_all",
      ]

  mongosetup:
    container_name: mongosetup
    image: "mongo-setup"
    build: "./mongo-setup"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb1

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongodb1:27011,mongodb2:27012,mongodb3:27013/?replicaSet=rs0
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb1
      - mongosetup
```

**mongo-setup.js**

```
rsconf = {
  _id : "rs0",
  members: [
      {
          "_id": 0,
          "host": "mongodb1:27011",
          "priority": 3
      },
      {
          "_id": 1,
          "host": "mongodb2:27012",
          "priority": 2
      },
      {
          "_id": 2,
          "host": "mongodb3:27013",
          "priority": 1
      }
  ]
}

rs.initiate(rsconf);
```

**mongo-setup.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -f /data/mongo-init.flag ]; then
    echo "Init replicaset"
    mongo mongodb://mongodb1:27011 mongo-setup.js
    touch /data/mongo-init.flag
else
    echo "Replicaset already initialized"
fi
```