# Cannot connect to MongoDB replicaSet cluster

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I set up a MongoDB cluster with Docker which uses replicaSet `rs0`.

Checking the status of the cluster everything seems fine:

```
{
  set: 'rs0',
  date: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:46.972Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("1"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 2,
  writeMajorityCount: 2,
  votingMembersCount: 3,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 3,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1671570000, i: 1 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T20:45:09.901Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("1"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671569099, i: 1 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671569099, i: 1 }), t: Long("-1") },
    numVotesNeeded: 2,
    priorityAtElection: 1,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    numCatchUpOps: Long("0"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T20:45:09.999Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T20:45:10.856Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'mongo1:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 973,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1671569109, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T20:45:09.000Z"),
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 1,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: 'mongo2:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 947,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:45.203Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:46.101Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo1:27017',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: 'mongo3:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 947,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }), t: Long("1") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:40.112Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:45.203Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2022-12-20T21:00:46.100Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: 'mongo1:27017',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 1,
      configTerm: 1
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("0")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1671570040, i: 1 })
}
```

I am using `pymongo` to connect to the cluster.
If I use just the node name of the primary node and connect directly to that, everything works just fine:

```py
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
collection = client["db"]["test"]
collection.insert_one({"abc": "def"})
print(list(collection.find()))
```

However, from what I can tell, this is NOT how you connect to a MongoDB cluster. Instead of directly choosing the primary Node, one instead should provide all Nodes in the cluster plus the replicaSet:

```py
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019?replicaSet=rs0")
collection = client["db"]["test"]
collection.insert_one({"abc": "def"})  # Hangs and eventually times out
```

The error raised:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 
mongo1:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known,
mongo3:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known,
mongo2:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known, 
Timeout: 30s, 
Topology Description: 
    <TopologyDescription 
        id: 63a2230d721313f82429a19e, 
        topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, 
        servers: [
            <ServerDescription ('mongo1', 27017) 
                server_type: Unknown, 
                rtt: None, 
                error=AutoReconnect('mongo1:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')>, 
            <ServerDescription ('mongo2', 27017) 
                server_type: Unknown, 
                rtt: None, 
                error=AutoReconnect('mongo2:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')>, 
            <ServerDescription ('mongo3', 27017) 
                server_type: Unknown, 
                rtt: None, 
                error=AutoReconnect('mongo3:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')>]>
```

I believe this might be because mongo1/2/3 are not actual hostnames but rather docker containers which are only valid hostnames within the Docker network, meaning, to access those hostnames I'd have to run my Python script within the same network.

I also tested if secondary nodes are reachable if I use `localhost:27018` and indeed, they are. `pymongo` tells me that I cannot insert directly into a secondary node, which makes sense.

My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo1:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo1
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,mongo1
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mongoCluster
    volumes:
      - /mnt/workspace/mongodb-cluster/node1:/data/db
  mongo2:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo2
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,mongo2
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    networks:
      - mongoCluster
    volumes:
      - /mnt/workspace/mongodb-cluster/node2:/data/db
  mongo3:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo3
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,mongo3
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    networks:
      - mongoCluster
    volumes:
      - /mnt/workspace/mongodb-cluster/node3:/data/db

networks:
  mongoCluster:
    driver: bridge
```

I also tried to not use a dedicated network and instead give the docker containers access to the hostnetwork, thus being able to define the replicaSet with `localhost:<PORT>`. While I was able to bring up the cluster, I still get the same error when trying to use it from Python.

All that being said, my question is now how I need to change my Docker or `pymongo` configuration such that I can specify all nodes in the connection string.

Comment: Your analysis seems correct to me. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68674898/20042973) for additional details and steps for resolution

Answer (score 0):

You general you cannot mix hostnames and `localhost` alias. If one ReplicaSet member is `localhost` then all members needs to be `localhost`, they must differ only in the port.

According `rs.status()` the members are `mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017`, thus the connection string must be accordingly

```
MongoClient("mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017?replicaSet=rs0")
```

Or you use `localhost` when you initiate the ReplicaSet:

```
rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27017" },
      { _id: 1, host: "localhost:27018" },
      { _id: 2, host: "localhost:27019" }
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: Just to note, `mongo1....`  connection string will work only from within docker network, i.e. another docker container, not the host system. The `localhost:27017....` members will work only when docker is running with `--network="host"` option. Otherwise localhost will refer to the container itself.

Comment: I already elaborated on this in my question and even using network=host does not work.

Comment: @BasicCoder sorry, but you did not. There is no way the error is the same if you initiated the replica set as Wernfried suggested.