# How to test MongoDB update/delete scripts without saving the changes? Transactions?

Tags: mongodb, docker, transactions

I'm trying to test some update / delete scripts against a localhost MongoDB server (which is a docker instance).

eg.

```
update all users, set age = 50
delete all users where eyes = blue

select all users
```

If I was to do this with SQL, I would wrap the those three queries inside a TRANSACTION.

So I had a look online to doing transactions with MongoDB and it feels like it's a PITA -> I need a REPLICA SET, etc.

Is there a really easy way to:

- create a mongodb instance with docker
- write a script (like above) inside a transaction, and run this against that docker instance?

My reasoning for using a transaction is so i can change the data, get the current *version* of the data (after the change) .. eye ball the results ... and then roll back (revert) those changes. Then keep iterating through my script until I'm happy.

Here's some stuff I was trying to prove my point:

```
docker-compose.yml

version: '3.5'

services:

  mongodb.data:
    container_name: mongodb.data
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017 
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/mongo-data
```

and some mongo shell script I'm playing around with in Studio 3T:

```
// Start a session.
session = db.getMongo().startSession( { readPreference: { mode: "primary" } } );

// Start a transaction
session.startTransaction( { readConcern: { level: "local" }, writeConcern: { w: "majority" } } );

usersCollection = session.getDatabase("users").users;

usersCollection.find(
    { 
        "_id.userId" : "abcde1234"
    }
);


usersCollection.update(
    { "_id.userId" : "abcde1234" },
    {
        $set: {
            tags: Date()
        } 
    },
    { multi:true }
);


session.abortTransaction();
//session.commitTransaction();


session.endSession();
```

and the error I get when I try to use a transaction:

```
WriteCommandError({
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos",
    "code" : 20,
    "codeName" : "IllegalOperation"
})
```

Is this even possible with a simple MongoDB setup?

Comment: You can have a replica set with 1 member. It won't be much different from a standalone from durability point of view but it will use opplog which is required for client sessions and transactions.

Comment: So does this mean I need to change my docker-compose file to have some _extra_ argument that says: "yo mongodb .. start up with this port, blah blah .. AND .. be a replica set?"

Comment: yep. "be a replica set" syntax discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190267/replica-set-mongo-docker-compose Adopt it to a single instance an you are good.

Comment: the mongo docker image strips off --replSet argument when using authentication. you need to jump through hoops to setup a replicaset if using the official docker image. easiest thing is to just turn off authentication. then it works. [see here](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/VisitorLog/tree/main/docker) for an example docker setup without auth.