# docker mongo for single (primary node only) replica set (for development)?

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, mongodb-replica-set

This is the portion of the dockerfile that has served us well to date.  However, now I need to convert this to be a single node replica set (for transactions to work).  I don't want any secondary or arbiter - just the primary node.  What am I missing to get this working?

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:4.4.3
  container_name: mongo
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: myPass
  command: mongod --port 27017
  ports:
    - '27017:27017'
  volumes:
    - ./data/mongodb:/data/db
    - ./data/mongodb/home:/home/mongodb/
    - ./configs/mongodb/mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh:ro
```

Comment: That looks like a standalone configuration, what did you do to make it into a replica set?

Comment: The bitnami MongoDB will provide that for you. Everything you need is here: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb

Answer (score 3):

Got it working.  I inserted the following into the block in my question above:

```
hostname: mongodb
volumes:
  - ./data/mongodb/data/log/:/var/log/mongodb/
# the healthcheck avoids the need to initiate the replica set
healthcheck:
  test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo -u root -p imagiaRoot --quiet) -eq 1
  interval: 10s
  start_period: 30s
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for Mongo 6 (which drops mongo for mongosh, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/#the-mdb-shell-versus-the-legacy-mongo-shell).

```
hostname: mongodb
image: mongo:latest
restart: unless-stopped
command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]
volumes:
  - mongodb-data:/data/db
healthcheck:
  test: 'test $$(mongosh --eval "rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok" --quiet) -eq 1'
  interval: 10s
  start_period: 30s
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: doesn't work without keyfile

Comment: @Vlad I don't remember having done anything with a keyfile. Can you explain? This is basically the most upvoted answer in this thread, but updated with the new cli.

Comment: it doesn't start because you didn't specify a key file but it is required now

Comment: Starting with which version of mongo? I tested it with 6.0.6, and he doesn't complain. At which point does he request the key file? This is for a dev database, without security, might that influence the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to initiate the replica set via the `healthcheck`. I used the bash script below instead. For **Windows users**, be sure to call your DB with the name of your computer. For example:
`mongodb://DESKTOP-QPRKMN2:27017`

### run-test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running docker-compose"
docker-compose up -d

echo "Waiting for DB to initialize"
sleep 10

echo "Initiating DB"
docker exec mongo_container mongo --eval "rs.initiate();"

echo "Running tests"

# test result
if go test ./... -v
then
  echo "Test PASSED"
else
  echo "Test FAILED"
fi

# cleanup
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml down
```

### docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongo:
    hostname: $HOST
    container_name: mongo_container
    image: mongo:5.0.3
    volumes:
      - ./test-db.d
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    command: ["--replSet", "test", "--bind_ip_all"]
```

This forum post was very helpful: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/docker-compose-replicasets-getaddrinfo-enotfound/14301/4